# Is it possible to insert html into the <Head> section of NextJS?

Tags: html, next.js, meta-tags

I have a backend that returns meta tags for a specific page. I would like to insert this response into the Head section of my page component.

I can insert html into React using `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: response.someHtml}} />`.

Is it possible to do the same for the `<Head>` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a BasePage component and render the `Head` component inside. This BasePage component will wrap up all the pages.

```
import HeadTags from "./Head";

const BasePage = (props) => {
  const {
    // you might have more props but those are related to the Heads
    children,
    title,
    metaDescription,
  } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <HeadTags
        title={title}
        metaDescription={metaDescription}
        canonicalPath={canonicalPath}
      ></HeadTags>
      // you mightadd more logic here
    </>
  );
};
```

You can define HeadTags components

```
const HeadTags = (props) => { 
  const {
    title = "Default tile",
    metaDescription = "default metaDescriptino",
  } = props;

  return (
    <Head>
      <title>{title}</title>
      {/* mobile devices by default takes the content from desktop and squueze it. But if you want it to be responsive */}
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta name="description" key="description" content={metaDescription} />
      // you could add more tags  
    </Head>
  );
};
```

Now since your page is wrapped by BasePage, you can pass the props to BasePage and it will pass it to `HeadTags` component so you will set meta data dynamically based on your backend returning metatags.

Comment: it's just a wrapper component. I need to eject html in head section. Without props or some "hardcoded "<title> or <meta> tags